# Is there a reference document for Microsoft typescript types?

Tags: typescript

Just starting with Typescript (with previous JS and C# experience) and I have an error

> "Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.\n  Type 'Node' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement':  ....

so I wanted to find out the correct type for the `HTMLElement` that I was using (i.e. one that knows about cloning). VSCode has installed the file `lib.dom.d.ts' which defines all these types, but is there a reference document somwhere that I can use to find the type I need (and any others I might need in future?)

Comment: Does the MDN documentation help you?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node